# Wordpress - custom image sizes not working

Tags: php, wordpress, image-resizing

I am having trouble with using custom image size.

I have this in function.php:

```
//function to call first uploaded image in functions file
function main_image() {
$files = get_children('post_parent='.get_the_ID().'&post_type=attachment
&post_mime_type=image&order=desc');
  if($files) :
$keys = array_reverse(array_keys($files));
$j=0;
$num = $keys[$j];
$image=wp_get_attachment_image($num, 'test', true);
$imagepieces = explode('"', $image);
$imagepath = $imagepieces[1];
$main=wp_get_attachment_url($num);
    $template=get_template_directory();
    $the_title=get_the_title();
print "<img src='$main' alt='$the_title' />";
endif;
}

add_image_size('test', 145, 145, true);
```

So what this does it check for the post's thumbnail, and if there is none, it searches to the first image in a post. So far so good, but I can't get it to display the image size that I want.

wp_get_attachment_image($num, 'test', true); should be displaying the 'test' size, which is created when uploaded (I also ran regenerate thumbnails, and all the images have been resized). But no matter what I enter instead of test (full, medium, thumbnail, etc), the code always call the full image (which gets squished to the 145x145 size instead of displaying the cropped thumbnail).

The code is from http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-set-a-default-fallback-image-for-wordpress-post-thumbnails/ (its old code, so probably some change in WP is making this fail).

Its the last thing I need to do to finish a site.